# Any tips for running more action based and less tactical encounters?

Tags: encounter-design, dnd-next-playtest

I've been using "tactical minis" games for all my games as of now, specifically Savage Worlds and 4E which has been my bread and butter.

Just recently we picked up D&D Next Playtest (Oct 2013) to start playing, and I can't stop reading everywhere this is "easier to play with simulationism" and "playable without an encounter map", the later saving me plenty of time of planning.

However something I noticed yesterday on our first play is that I didn't know how to react to my player's ideas; tho they asked me for "logical" stuff I couldn't see that happening on a tactical tabletop game, but on an interactive narrative game (and RPGs are supposed to be that). They were being chased by a swarm of Vampire Flowers on a meadow, and without a map I just imagined they ran, turned back ocassionaly to shoot stuff, and made a boring fight as the flowers couldn't get thru their armors and when my evil master plans of making them dull and slow made it, things never got interestign cuz the dragonborn just exterminated the swarm with a single Dragon Breathe in a pretty fireworks explosion, so in my opinion something that took 3 rounds (12 seconds in D&D Time) shouldn't have been exciting...

So, I find myself in trouble desiging encounters without tactical focus, specially cuz I'm already tired of spending hour and hour thinking which floor tiles to use to create a tactical environment like 4E pushed yourself to do, and because it seems now I can think of more ways to make encounters worthy... but I don't know how.

Comment: It might be helpful to poke around here with the search term "theater of the mind", we've got a couple of good [tag:dnd-next] questions on the subject. Here's one: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/38217/1084

Answer (score 6):

**Action Movies**

The easiest source of material is action movies.

How many action movies have fights in empty rooms or flat empty areas?  Not too many.  Action movies always have fights where there are things to climb, knock over, break, set on fire, knock someone over/into, sharp things, burning things, things to fall off of, etc.

Whereas in a grid based game, you'd be looking where to place these exactly and how many squares, and so on, here, you're just going to draw a very sketchy map and write down some easy items that might come into play.

**Castle Hall Example**

A smaller greeting hall, with a couple of round tables and chairs.

- Shuttered windows w/o glass - someone can be pushed out of these for a 50' fall.
- Tapestries - can be pulled down and over someone to entangle/blind them
- Braziers filled with hot coals - push someone into them, knock them over onto the ground
- A serving tray - can be used as a temporary shield against ranged weapons, or thrown
- Stairs - the hall is entered by stairs leading down to the central entrance and exited by stairs up to the high landing.  it's about 20' of stairs either way, great for a tumble if you want to push someone down.
- Display Armor - two suits of armor stand on display, they can be knocked over or used as cover.

You can get to the point where you don't even have to list everything out like this - you might write down 6-7 items and know how to improvise what they do, or pull up an image of a location on the internet and use that as reference.  Or even a sentence for a movie reference ("The grand cathedral from Castle Cagliostro") as shorthand for yourself.

**More than Decorations**

So, you've got all this stuff, right?  And often enough in a game, players will ignore it if you don't give it some mechanical value.  An easy way to give all this stuff some value is to give it bonuses to hit, bonuses to defense if you're hiding behind it, or some kind of penalty or stun to the enemies if you use it upon them.

If the object can only be used once, I generally like to slap a +4 to hit on it and significant damage and/or stun... enough the players will seriously consider it in favor of just using their weapons.  "Used once" applies to things like "knocking over a bookshelf onto an enemy" but also applies to things which any intelligent enemies will avoid after you do it the first time, such as "pushed a guy out the window".

Reusable stuff often either requires some other defensive tradeoff ("Yes, you can keep throwing barrels onto the bar area below, but you're at -4 AC when you do because lifting barrels is a particularly vulnerable position") or gives a lower bonus.

Initially, tell the players a few of these ideas - fighters and thieves are probably going to be the best to think about how to use their environment to their advantage.  As players become more adept at playing, you can simply describe the room and they can take advantage of it themselves.

**Hazards**

Hazards are great.  Aside from being the kind of thing you want to toss your enemy into, and avoid getting tossed into yourself, you can also make them shifting/moving hazards.  which then forces the players to keep moving or doing things.

Hazards can also be weighted to affect some more than others.  Lizardmen don't find a swamp hazardous, but they're totally happy to bear hug you and drag you under the water in your heavy plate armor.   The burning building that has chunks of wood falling down is bad for everyone, but maybe the halfling can run under tables without crawling or kneeling and keep fighting just fine.

Consider what a Hazard does, consider if it can and does move, and how fast.  It can be a way to push players into new areas and opens up ideas like trying to run past enemies or hold the enemies into an area while the hazard does the work.

**The most boring way to play D&D**

"I roll to hit.  I miss."  "The goblin hits. 2 points of damage." "I hit, 4 points of damage." over and over.

If the best choice in a fight is the same attack that the players ALWAYS use, there's not reason to do anything else.  At which point you're playing the dice version of the card game War - where choice is irrelevant to luck.

Use the ideas above to push your play into anything BUT that.  Sure, sometimes, just swinging the sword is the best idea.  But many times, pushing an enemy, throwing something, knocking something over should be also great choices for players.

Also reward players when they think of using something in a way you didn't consider before - "They're trapped under the fallen chandelier?  I'm casting Heat Metal!"  "Oh geez, aside from the damage, I think it's time for a morale check! Too much pain is a good reason to run..."

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to (yet again) give another opinion-based answer, as someone already covered the theater of the mind search (an excellent option by the way!).  I did have an interesting question come to mind, which I think will lead to the solution.

**Are you having fun with your game as the DM?**

So, the reason I ask this is I've noticed as a DM that if I'm not having fun, my players fall into this same trap of by-the-numbers play too.  Its really depressing, not only because it sucks the fun out of the game for me, but if I'm not having fun, the players aren't generally having a good time either.  Remember that part of your role as the DM is party host, make sure everyone's having fun and not just tossing dice at a pool of HP which it seems that your encounter devolved into.  While they had a solid tactic as players (good) they were able to exploit the mechanics (bad) to make the encounter trivial and boring (very bad).

While i don't like killing characters, there's too much paperwork, I really do enjoy the sadistic glee of catching them with their pants down and dragging them behind the shed.  Namely? If they start running, spawn out some more vampire flowers, knock a couple of HP off them (on the fly adjustment to compensate), and put them in the PC's path.  This does a few things.  First, it lends a seemingly innocent monster a very sinister twist since it now looks like they were waiting for the PCs to do this.  Second, it adds a bit of cinematic flare when one of the PCs does the inevitable, "Guys! There's more of 'em!" bit -- I'm fond of even describing what the camera would do in that situation -- and finally, it raises the challenge for the PCs and makes them have to think "Wait, what if this entire meadow is full of them...."

You have a great plan on the monsters, and i think your encounter design is great, but make sure that you're having fun (your second paragraph suggests you're not) and the players will end up having fun as well as well.